# Where I can get payer_id for executing payment (paypal)?

Tags: python, django, rest, paypal, payment

Working with PayPal Python REST SDK. After payment created we need to execute this payment. At https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/execute.py is code sample. But when executing payment

```
if payment.execute({"payer_id": "DUFRQ8GWYMJXC"}):  # return True or False
    print("Payment[%s] execute successfully" % (payment.id))
else:
print(payment.error)
```

we need to write payer_id. But how I can take it? Any ideas or code examples?

Answer (score -1):

The payerid is returned in the host headers on the callback - Alternatively, you can do the following..

In the process of creating a sale, do...

```
saleinfo_ = {"intent":"sale",
"redirect_urls":{
    "return_url":("myurlonsuccess"),
    "cancel_url":("myurlonfail")
    },
    "payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},
    "transactions":[
        {"amount":{"total":out_totaltopay_, "details":{"tax":out_taxes_, "subtotal":out_subtotal_}, "currency":symbol_}, "description":description_}

payment_ = Payment(saleinfo_)

if (payment_.create()):
    token_ = payment_.id
```

Then when the return callback arrives, use...

```
payment_ = Payment.find(token_)

if (payment_ != None):
    payerid_ = payment_.payer.payer_info.payer_id

    if (payment_.execute({"payer_id":payerid_})):
        ....
```

The json data received in the find process is similar to the following

```
{'payment_method': 'paypal', 'status': 'VERIFIED', 'payer_info': {'shipping_address': {'line1': '1 Main St', 'recipient_name': 'Test Buyer', 'country_code': 'US', 'state': 'CA', 'postal_code': '95131', 'city': 'San Jose'}, 'first_name': 'Test', 'payer_id': '<<SOMEID>>', 'country_code': 'US', 'email': 'testbuyer@mydomain.com', 'last_name': 'Buyer'}}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: as the result of your code I receive: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'payer_info'